# How can we use form directly without using drupal form handler

Tags: forms

I want to post a html form into block as content and wanted to submit the form to a page.
where I will need to get the form values using $_POST and do some process on it.

How can i do that without using drupal_form(), drupal_form_submit() handlers.

Any way we can achieve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just get the HTML output of an existing drupal form then this will get you there:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('drupal_form_id');
$form['#action'] = url('mypath');
print render($form);
```

Replace `'drupal_form_id'` with whatever registered Drupal form you want and `url('mypath')` with whatever URL you want to post to.

Comment: Shawn, Its not an existing drupal form, Its just normal html form designed directly in the tpl file, hence It has no drupal gen form id or other hidden form fields.

Comment: In that case, you want to use `theme_render_template($template_file, $variables)`. It will output the HTML you want. See the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7) for more info.